# Showing the following map is surjective

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to use the implicit function theorem to prove that $Sp(4,\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group. I have defined the map $f:M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathit{Skew}_{\mkern 1.5mu 4\times4}$ by $f(X) = XJX^T$, where

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
0_{2\times2} & I_{2\times 2} \\
-I_{2\times 2} & 0_{2\times 2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then, I get that $Sp(4,\mathbb{R}) = f^{-1}(J)$. Now, I need to show that

$$\left. f_*\right|_X :T_X M_{4\times 4} \to T_{f(X)} \mathit{Skew}_{\mkern1.5mu 4\times4}$$

is surjective. Does anyone have any advice on how I might be able to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a canonical isomorphism $T_X\mathcal{M}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathcal{M}_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{R})$,
$T_{f(X)}Skew_{4 \times 4} \cong Skew_{4 \times 4}$ such that

$(d_Xf)(Y)=XJY^t-YJX^t=-2\pi(YJX^t)$ where $\pi$ is the natural projection on $Skew_{4 \times 4}$.

Now, what can you say about $Y \longmapsto YJX^t$ if $X$ is symplectic?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this doesn't really help me. I'm not familiar with this "canonical isomorphism". Could you maybe provide more details? Is there another way to show that $f_*$ is surjective?

Comment: If you have a finite-dimensional affine space $E$, with underlying vector space $V$, and a point $x \in E$, then you can assimilate a tangent vector to $E$ at $x$ (seen as an equivalence class of continuously differentiable paths going through $x$) to an element of $V$ (the usual derivative of the path when it is at $x$). This is a linear map, and it is an isomorphism. This is what I call the « canonical isomorphism ». As far as I know, there isn’t really a way to prove your surjectivity without translating the geometric language into linear algebra, ie use the « canonical isomorphisms ».